# Perform query search for elasticsearch using httpclient

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, console-application, httpclient

If I am trying to perform a simple query search just like I would in the CLI of kibana, would I need to use a `HttpResponseMessage = client.GetAsJsonAsync()` instead of a `.PostAsJsonAsync()` when using HttpClient()?

```
GET customer-simulation-es-app-logs-*/_search
{

  "query": {
    "match": {
      "level" : "information"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as i know, nothing should be joined with the query attribut, I guess the size field is making an exception somewhere. I advice you to remove it and retest and try using the size into the query directly

Comment: Really? Was not aware of that, because normally you can in the CLI. However, I went ahead and removed `size` from query completely and ran it as so and still am getting the 400 (bad request). I even removed `JObject.Parse(query)` and placed `query` inside of the `PostAsJsonAsync()` but that did not help either.

Comment: can you add the EsSource object here please ?

Comment: Please see updated post. I have that line commented out because I was getting a 400 bad request before. Unless I was doing it incorrectly..